# In React, How to pass the selected dropdown data to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, use-state

I have been trying to make a multi-select dropdown for my project, where a person can select which school subjects they teach at the website's registration. But I have been having troubles in regards of passing the selected value to the declared state in a simple-option dropdown.

When I try to make the POST request to my API (made with NodeJS, express and mongoDB for database), the console.log returns that the subject object has three arrays with all the subject data. I want to pass only the _id field, since it was what was requested.

How should I get only the subjects _id when my API GET request returns all fields?

Code for reference:

API call

```
async function listActiveSubjects() {
    const response = await api.get("/subject");
    return response.data;
}
```

JSON returned from the request:

```
{
  "subjects": [
     {
            "isActive": true,
            "_id": "6001e71606a211004877f6e1",
            "name": "Subject 1",
            "description": "Subject 1 description",
            "__v": 0
      },
      {
            "isActive": true,
            "_id": "6001e71606a211004877f6e1",
            "name": "Subject 2",
            "description": "Subject 2 description",
            "__v": 0
      },
  ]
}
```

React functional component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { listActiveSubjects } from '../../../../services/subjects';

const TeacherClassInfo = props => {
    const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState();
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState({ _id: ''})

    const handleListActiveSubjects = async () => {
        const getSubjects = await listActiveSubjects();
        setSubjects(getSubjects);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        handleListActiveSubjects()
    }, []);

    const onChange = (key, _id) => {
        setSelected(() => ({
            [key]: _id,
        }))
    }

    return(
        <select>
          {subjects &&
            subjects.subjects.map((subjects) => {
              return (
                <option
                  onChange={_id => onChange(_id)}
                    key={subjects._id}
                    value={selected[subjects._id]}>
                      {subjects.name}
                 </option>
              );
           })
         }
      </select>  
    );
```

The output that the log shows is:

```
subjects: Array(2)
    0: {isActive: true, _id: "6001e71606a211004877f6e1", name: "Subject 1", description: "Subject 1 
description", __v: 0}
    1: {isActive: true, _id: "6001e73106a211004877f6e2", name: "Subject 2", description: "Subject 2 description", __v: 0}
length: 2
```

And in my understanding it should be:

```
subjects: Array(1)
    0: {_id: "6001e71606a211004877f6e1"}
length: 1
```

, as is configured on the database.

From other tutorials and questions I saw here, this was supposed to set the selected id, but unfortunately it hasn't been working as expected. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Your `onChange()` method is expecting two arguments but you're only passing one. Also it should just be `onChange={()=>onChange(_id)}`

Comment: I changed how you told me to, but I couldn't really understand, and it did not change anything, visually, at least. If it's not too much trouble, would you care to explain?

Comment: Is your select working? as it stands you are passing only one argument: `() => onChange(_id)` , but it is expecting two: `onChange=(key, _id)=>{...}`, meaning that it is using the passed `_id` as the `key` and so effectively calling `setSelected(() => ({ [_id]: undefined, }))`

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately it's not. It is still passing all three values to the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return all the `_id` values in an array by using the `map()` method on the `response.data.subjects` array. This will loop over each subject and will create a new array based on the values returned in the callback. In this case it's the `_id` property value.

```
async function listActiveSubjects() {
  const response = await api.get("/subject");
  const ids = response.data.subjects.map(({ _id }) => _id);
  return ids;
}
```

This will result in:

```
[
  "6001e71606a211004877f6e1",
  "6001e73106a211004877f6e2",
]
```

Giving you only the strings that you need.